# trying to optimize Ceph CRUSH settings to optimal

Tags: 16.04, ceph

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on all my ceph servers and the ceph client machines. I'm using Ceph jewel release 10.2.3. I'm trying to update/tune the ceph crush variables to optimal:

```
ceph osd crush tunables optimal
```

which executes but then I am unable to create a RBD image and map that image on the client, getting the error:

```
libceph: mon0 99.999.X.41:6789 feature set mismatch, my 106b84a8ABC < server's 40106b84a8ADC, missing 400000000000000
```

Looking into this states that you can't use an older release client which I'm not, Redhat states that their 7.2 release doesn't support this and you have to set crush tunables to hammer. If I set:

```
ceph osd crush tunables hammer
```

everything works. I don't want to use old technology in crush, if I'm running jewel, I would like to use the new optimized settings in crush. I also modified crush to change all straw references to straw2 which still didn't help.

What are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have different kernels on Monitors and clients. There are certain requirements to the Kernel Version with which tunables features are supported.

To check out, whats actually missing on client side, check [this](http://ceph.com/geen-categorie/feature-set-mismatch-error-on-ceph-kernel-client/)

Comment: This is a link to a post on an external site, and may need further work to increase its value here, or moderation to remove. Please contemplate expanding your answer to include pertinent information rather than just a link. This will help the OP and others in the future, much more.